# TSQL: substring to include all numbers between 0-9 except 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the substring function in a case statment to return all numbers between 'B0' - 'B9'

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-9]'
```

but i do not want to return the number 'B5' in this list. I can get it working as this

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-4]'
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[6-9]'
```

but is there a way to add this to one line like the following?

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-9]' and not like 'B5'
```

**EDIT:**

how would you do this if you where dealing with numbers between 0-100 so the sql would be like

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3) like 'B[0-9][0-9]'
```

but you did not want to include 16 and 17?

Comment: No `LIKE` needed.  `... AND postcode <> 'B5'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[012346789]' -- No "5"
```

[LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) patterns are awesome.  Mini regex, if you will.

To carry this out to the tens place or more for numbers, you might want to consider putting these values into a table that you can use for a `join`, `exists` or `in`.

Or, since we're treating the numeric portion of this column as though they were numbers and not a string, this is a sign that they might have been better stored as two columns: one for the alpha, one for the numeric.

Barring any change to your schema, you might remove the alpha characters ad-hoc so you can compare them to a range of numbers, for example:

```
where cast(replace(postcode, 'B', '') as int) between 0 and 15
    or cast(replace(postcode, 'B', '') as int) between 18 and 100

where cast(right(postcode, len(postcode) - 1) as int) between 0 and 15
    or cast(right(postcode, len(postcode) - 1) as int) between 18 and 100
```

These are just a couple of possibilities.  You would know best how to massage your data.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would you do this if you where dealing with numbers between 0-100 so the sql would be like... WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3) like 'B[0-9][0-9]'... but you did not want to include 16 and 17?

Comment: At that point, I would like to have those values in a table that I could use for a join/exists/in.  You could also use multiple where conditions as other answers and comments have mentioned.  I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to have two ranges, removing the 5 from it:

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-46-9]'
```

Comment: I'm not certain but from the description of LIKE here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx nothing indicates multiple range does not work

Comment: @TimLehner : Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` to represent Not..   see [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)...

but why not Try

```
`WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-4]' Or   
      SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[6-9]'`
```

or you can put the ranges in  the same brackets

```
`WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 2) like 'B[0-46-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

For the single digit case (your original question) you got a bunch of great answers already. however without a real regular expression you can't solve the multi digit problem.

It seams that you have a list of values that you want to exclude. I that case you can use this:

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3) like 'B[0-9][0-9]'
 AND SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3) NOT IN ('B16', 'B17')
```

If the list of "excludables" is in a table use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
WHEN SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3) like 'B[0-9][0-9]'
 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.excludables AS ex WHERE ex.val = SUBSTRING (postcode, 1, 3))
```